# Vim Supertab: Pressing tab after dot doesn't complete

Tags: vim, supertab

Supertab works correctly in most cases.

I am writing a simple line of java `Integer.toHexString`. This has appeared in other parts of the file.

If I press tab after `In`, it gives me `Integer` correctly. If I press tab after `to` (another line), it gives me `toHexString` correctly, too. But, if I press tab after typing `Integer.` or `Integer.to`, tab automatically moves to the next line without any completion. (still in insert mode)

Here is my `.vimrc` the part related to supertab.

```
let g:SuperTabLongestHighlight = 1
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
autocmd FileType *
    \ if &omnifunc != '' |
    \   call SuperTabChain(&omnifunc, "<c-p>") |
    \ endif
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

Here is the result from running `:verbose imap <Tab>`

```
i  <Tab>         <Plug>SuperTabForward
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/supertab/plugin/supertab.vim
```

Comment: You can try Ctrl+x, Ctrl+o for omnicompletion, even if no plugin is installed :)

Comment: You or your plugin might have set `g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['.']`. Print the value of this variable in command line and check.

Comment: It is also found that SnipMate plugin might interfere with this setting. Check the plugin's issue tracker.